# How would I pull an image from an HTTP url and save to HTPS server and then load?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to figure out how to pull an image from a third party website that gets changed every so often. Basically I am using Vbulletin software and would like to avoid a mixed content warning - hosting an image (HTTP) from another site onto mine (HTTPS). I would like the function basically to call the image in php, save the image to a folder on my server and then a php function to call the saved image on my server and display it. Thoughts? Thanks. I keep getting a failure to open stream on file_get_contents...

```
    ob_start();


//Get the file
$content = file_get_contents("http://www.defconwarningsystem.com/current/defcon.jpg");
//Store in the filesystem.
$fp = fopen("/images/defcon/defcon.jpg", "w");
fwrite($fp, $content);
fclose($fp);


$html = ob_get_clean();
return $html;
```

Comment: please put some codes, from third party or your site. start do something, search for it and when you stock somewhere, ask your question.

Comment: What error message do you get?
Does your server allow calling file_get_contents?

Comment: I'm not sure, it is shared hosting. If for some reason it does not, is there another way around this?

Comment: you can try to activate `allow_url_fopen` inside php.ini (you might be able to just create one inside root folder if there is none)

Comment: Checked my .ini file and it had this:  allow_url_fopen = On ;

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://www.defconwarningsystem.com/current/defcon.jpg");
```

To

```
$content = file_get_contents("//defconwarningsystem.com/current/defcon.jpg");
```

And see if that works.

Comment: E_WARNING : type 2 -- file_get_contents(//www.defconwarningsystem.com/current/defcon.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory -- at line 4

Comment: Sorry. remove the www.

Comment: Well. I thought that would work, Try instead `<img src="//defconwarningsystem.com/current/defcon.jpg">`
I know that you said you were worried about a HTTPS issue, but when including scripts I do `<script src="//code.jquery/min-js.js"></script>`
That's not necessarily going to work, but I think it would in theory.

Comment: Sorry. That's the way I would go about. I'm not sure after that. If I think of anything I'll make sure to let you know.

Comment: That shouldn't make any difference afaik?

Comment: Typically it would. Say you're using outside scripts; you can include them with // instead of the http:// protocol and it will automatically include the correct version.

Comment: @MorganGreen That's correct in general but the image Kirk is trying to fetch is available via http (too), so this should not keep Kirk from fetching that file.

Answer (score 1):

If file_get_contents doesn't work try [cURL](http://php.net/manual/de/book.curl.php).
[See example usage on php reference](http://php.net/manual/de/curl.examples-basic.php)

Comment: That did not work either... I wonder if it is a shared hosting issue...?

Comment: Please explain "That did not work either". What happened? Any errors displayed? Anything shown inside your log files? Did you try fetching a "simple" text or html file you placed on your own server (but fetching it not via "/folderx/text.txt" but via "http://myurl.tld/folderx/text.txt") Same issues here?